# How to avoid using white space in react input field, when "onChange" is already reserved for different function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input field with the "onChange" event on them, that fetches elements of an array with the "forEach" method, and it works pretty well. But I also want to add one additional feature to input fields - to avoid typing blank spaces. How should I attach this additional feature?

I tried to use "onKeyDown" event to avoid white spaces but probably it gives me an error. Below is a code of input field:

**mainList.js**

```
<input
type="text"
className="form-control"
value={sprNotDeleted.value}
onKeyDown= 
{this.AttributeValidation(sprNotDeleted.value)}
onChange={this.inputChanged.bind(
this,
sprNotDeleted.id
)}
/>
```

**inputChanged()**

```
inputChanged = (index, e) => {
    const { sprNotDeleted } = this.state;
    sprNotDeleted.forEach(point => {
      point.value = point.id === index ? e.target.value : point.value;
    });
    this.setState({ sprNotDeleted, isEdit: false });
  };
```

**AttributeValidation()**

```
 AttributeValidation(value) {
    this.setState({
      sprNotDeleted: value.replace(/\s/g, "")
    });
  }
```

Here is a corresponding error if I will use "onKeyDown":
    TypeError: sprNotDeleted.map is not a function

Comment: Well there's a few things. Firstly, if you set `sprNotDeleted ` to a string, then it won't have access to functions like `.map` or `.forEach` so you'll get that type error. Secondly, in `inputChanged()` you're directly mutating the state, which you shouldn't do in React. Destructuring `sprNotDeleted` still preserves its references, so in the `.forEach` when you mutate its values, you're directly mutating state. Finally, in `inputChanged` you treat `sprNotDeleted` like an array, but then in your `AttributeValidation` you treat it like a string. Is it a string or an array?

Comment: Ok, @Jayce444, I understdand that it is wrong to mutate state directly, and will try to avoid this later(probably because don't know how to do it now). Answering to your third question sprNotDeleted is an array. I just tried  those option on __AttributeValidation()__, but didn't mention that it was array-string problem. Also,  __AttributeValidation()__ has been changed to an array format, but still I don't know how to avoid typing white spaces to user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observed that, for the onKeyDown you are not binding the event to this.

**onKeyDown= {this.AttributeValidation.bind(
        this,
        sprNotDeleted.value
        )}**

```
<input
    type="text"
    className="form-control"
    value={sprNotDeleted.value}
    onKeyDown= {this.AttributeValidation.bind(
    this,
    sprNotDeleted.value
    )}
    onChange={this.inputChanged.bind(
    this,
    sprNotDeleted.id
    )}
/>
```

As you are accessing the this scope recommending to use this bind()

Instead of handling through onKeyDown() can you try using pattern regex handling as its a input type text you can handle it through pattern itself?

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    pattern="[^\s]+"
/>
```

Happy Coding!!

Comment: ,thanks for good suggestion, I tried "pattern" without "onKeyDown" but still it seems like I can use white spaces while typing in `<input>`.

Comment: Just found, that my `input` not within the `form`, that is why pattern is not working.

Comment: :) Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really tried ur code, but it seems like u have several problems here:

1. In `onKeyDown` event handler, function `this.AttributeValidation` is called directly without being passed as an event handler. So that function is executed which most likely not what u want.
2. When `this.AttributeValidation` is executed, `sprNotDeleted` becomes a String instead of an array, which does not have `foreach` method attached in its prototype.

This is for suggestion:

In `onChange` handler, consider creating an arrow function instead of bind the function, since u used arrow function for defining the function, binding to `this` will be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

you can use keydown on input,for first word. for react hooks

```js
const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === " " && name.length===0) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}/>
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" onKeyDown={handleKeydown}/>
```

this will prevent space on first but you cant add spaces in any sentence afterwards for that you can give condition of length

Answer (score 0):

I used this for my use case,

- I had a controlled state
- Wanted the user to allow typing empty spaces/white spaces
- Can validate the state on external event like a button click

```
<form action=''>

<InputComponent
  placeholder="Enter a name"
  value={folderName}
  onChange={(value) => {
    setFolderName(value);
  }}
/>;


<ButtonComponent
  variant={"primary"}
  disabled={folderName.length === 0 || folderName.trim().length === 0}
  onClick={handleClick}
>
  SAVE
</ButtonComponent>;

</form>
```